# What is going on with my PHP class variable?

Tags: php

I made this stupidly simple PHP file containing

```
<?php

class stuff {
    private $var;
}

?>
```

and results in this error when run:

> **Parse error**: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in . . . on line **4**

To make things even more confusing, it functions normally on a different domain with the same host. Surely the folder and domain have nothing to do with whether class properties can be defined. What is going on here??

Comment: Which version of PHP? On Windows or *nix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's legal PHP code. I'd guess you're testing it in a machine that has PHP 4 installed. Support for PHP 4 has been discontinued for a long time; it's strongly recommended  to upgrade.

Comment: Bam! That's the answer! Turns out I accidentally ticked a PHP 4 checkmark on the control panel for only that domain.

Comment: I also had no idea PHP 4 didn't support classes. It's apparently had that feature for a shorter time than I though.

Comment: @Vor It supports classes, though they're little more than arrays with methods. In particular, you cannot have private or protected members.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Public variables didn't seem to work in PHP 4 either.

Comment: @Vor They're all public. The `public` keyword did not exist, though. You have to use the `var` keyword to declare them.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like PHP 4 is active on that particular domain/folder of yours.

Comment: Yup! That was the problem. Both PHP 4 and 5 were installed, but not to my knowledge at the time, 4 was set as the primary version.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like php4.

put

```
<?php phpinfo();>
```

into a file and view it from a web browser. That will let you determine the version.

Comment: Never post short tags, not all environments have theirs on and it can make debugging code very confusing when your trying to help some one who is already confused.

Comment: Good catch, sorry about that, changed.

Comment: Sure enough, it was PHP 4. I've enabled 5 on the server, and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

You mean a different domain hosted on the same server? It could be an error with your php installation.